# Brother MFC-490CW won't print

Tags: printer, thinkpad, multi-function-printer

Suddenly nothing prints.  My IT pro logged in remotely for a few minutes and thought all settings looked good. Here's what I've tried:

1. replaced all inkjets, which had been getting very low
2. turned off and unplugged printer, turned off Lenovo Thinkpad Laptop (still new); plugged printer in and turned everything on;
3. replaced printer cable;
4. plugged printer cable into the other port on the laptop;
5. troubleshot through Brother on line;
6. my Brother is set to be the default printer and it is on line
7. I have been taking the laptop to work to use in zoom meetings and I was able to print there, to my Ricoh at work (I was thinking maybe I messed up a setting at work Wednesday after printing to the Ricoh because then I brought it home and I think that's when it stopped working at home).

When I hit the print command the dialog box comes and goes very quickly (today the web site from which I was trying to print a receipt shut down completely), and there is nothing in the print queue though I have attempted print jobs repeatedly.

I have Windows 10 and was going to try Customer Support there after a good night's sleep! Any ideas will be appreciated and remember, I am a total technological dummy.

Thanks!

Comment: If you've had the June 2020 Windows 10 update applied, se https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-printing-issues-after-latest-update-windows-10 . In future posts, mention OS details.

Comment: Another thing you could try is uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers. By installing and uninstalling, it will also hopefully ask you about allowing/blocking anything with the firewall. Ensure that private and public networks are allowed.

Comment: Thank you all very very much. I will try all this and let you know.

Comment: Your IT pro logged in? Is this company equipment?

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall the printer completely. Do the following:

1. From Devices and Printers, delete the printer
2. Go to Control Panel > Programs & Features and delete any software relating to the printer
3. Go back to Devices & Printers, click on any other printer and select "Print server properties" from the menu that appears. Click the "Drivers" tab and relate any instances of your printer (there may not be any)
4. Now reinstall.

If that doesn't help, try resetting the entire printer to factory defaults, [as follows](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/80195/%7E/how-do-i-reset-the-brother-machine-to-factory-default-setttings%3F):

1. Unplug the interface cable if selecting Network or All Settings.
2. Press Menu.
3. Press the UP OR DOWN ARROW key to choose Initial Setup. Press OK.
4. Press the UP OR DOWN ARROW key to choose Reset. Press OK.
5. Press the UP OR DOWN ARROW key to choose the reset function you want to use. Press OK.
6. To reset the settings, press 1 and go to Step 7.
7. You will be asked to reset the machine. To reset the machine, press 1. The machine will begin the reset.

Note that this will make the printer forget all its network settings, fax pnone numbers, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will find the courage to try all this in the next few days and I will let you know.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, try rebooting everything with the printer being last, and then press the test print button on the printer, or page alignment if available. These printers seem to have finicky drivers

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to hear your opinion about the drivers. Maybe it isn't me! I will try this and will post the results in the next few days.